# Reacting to third-party application form events using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, event-handling

I would like to know how I should code my VB.net application to react to the form load event in a third-party application (also written in VB.net)

To test, I have created two basic programs,  one with two forms (program A)  and one (program B) that attempts to the listen to program A's appropriate form load event. I have tried using WithEvents but it does not get fired when Program's A second form loads.

Here is the code for Program A:

```
Public Class StartPage
  Public WithEvents loadtimer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

  Private Sub StartPage_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    loadtimer.Interval = 1000
    loadtimer.Enabled = True
    loadtimer.Start()
  End Sub

  Private Sub loadtimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles loadtimer.Tick
    loadtimer.Stop()
    SystemStatus.Show()
  End Sub

End Class


Public Class SystemStatus
  Inherits StartPage

  Private Sub StartPage_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      Me.Label1.Text = "This is the form that I want to listen for the load event"
      Me.loadtimer.Enabled = False
  End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the code for Program B:

```
Imports Program_A

Public Class ListeningForm
  Dim WithEvents testlisten As New Program_A.SystemStatus

  Private Sub testlisten_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles testlisten.Load
    Label1.Text = "SystemStatus form loaded"
  End Sub

  Private Sub ListeningForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Label1.Text = "Waiting for SystemStatus load event..."
  End Sub
End Class
```

I am quite new when it comes to programming so maybe this is not even possible or I just haven't been understanding what I've been reading. In any case please enlighten me as to what my next course of action should be.

Thanks very much in advance,
theoleric

Comment: Show some relevant code.

Comment: @DonA there is some relevant code. Is this enough for you to help me out now?

Comment: You need to show where the class `ListeningForm` is instantiated. More code please.

Comment: Is the `Program_A.SystemStatus` a form or a class object?

Comment: @DonA oops I guess I got ahead of myself. I added the rest of the code

Comment: @Enigmativity I not exactly sure what instantiated means but I added the code that I forgot.

Comment: So its a form. Are you calling `.Show()`?

Comment: @DONA Correct me if I misunderstood your question but I believe that is what `SystemStatus.Show` is doing in the `loadtimer.tick` event handler of Program_A

Comment: But that's not the same as the `testlisten` object I am talking about. Where you are calling it - you are calling the default form instead of the of an instance of the form which `testlisten` is.

Comment: Looking at your code, why are you making another form that inherits from `StartPage` and calling it from an instance of itself - this is very confusing. Could you try to explain what you are wanting to do?

Comment: @theoleric - You don't show the code where you are showing the `ListeningForm` form. If you don't have an instance of that form open then it can't respond to events.

Comment: @DonA Essentially I am trying to mimic a third-party application that uses `Inherits Form` for the specific form that I will need to respond to form events. That is the only reason I used the `Inherits` statement. I didn't need to, but I wanted to make sure I could react to an inherited form's form_load event. The `Start_Page` inherited form could essentially be any form at all. I just need to learn how to respond to its events from totally separate programs.

Comment: @Enigmativity In Program_B Listening Form is the start-up form. when the program starts, a instance of the form starts and thus should start responding to events, should it not?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what your asking.

```
Imports Program_A

Public Class ListeningForm
 Dim WithEvents testlisten As New SystemStatus

 Private Sub testlisten_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles testlisten.Load
  ' now this event will fire
  Label1.Text = "SystemStatus form loaded"
 End Sub

 Private Sub ListeningForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Label1.Text = "Waiting for SystemStatus load event..."
  ' the load event will not fire until you call this
  testlisten.Show() 
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This does in fact work but I may have mislead you. I may be taking the wrong approach to my goal. What I envision ultimately is Program_B running in the background while Program_A does it thing. The moment the SystemStatus form (or any specified form) is loaded in Program_A, I need Program_B to see the event in Program_A and react accordingly.

Comment: Do both of these programs belong to you? Do they both of them belong to the same project?

Comment: Technically, both of these programs do belong to me as I created them as a test bed for my end goal. Pratically speaking, however, when I use what I learn here on the end goal, Program_A does not belong to me and I can only alter Program_B. I can peer in to Program_A using JustDecompile though.

Comment: So `Program_A` is running as a separate instance exe, and you want `program_B` to listen to events - then no. Plus this could be an attempt to do malicious acts by it's wording if you do not own or have rights to one of them. We cannot help with this type of work.